# SAPUI5 Wizard: How do I skip a Step of the Wizard?

Tags: sapui5, wizard

I m trying to dynamically skip a Step of the wizard. Means when onNext() a condition will be checked. If the step do not fulfill the condition, the step will be skiped. So the step will not be activated.

I dont know yet how to desactivate/activate a step, so that the step will still be on the wizard bar but the user will not go into.

Any suggestions please ?

Thanks

Comment: You should use Wizard's branching functionality: [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api//symbols/sap.m.Wizard.html). [Example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/Wizard.html?sap-ui-debug=true&sap-ui-language=bg&sap-ui-theme=sap_belize&sap-ui-accessibility=true)

Comment: Thank you. I thought about that possibility already but it was not really what I wanted to achieve. Branching is not dynamic enough and also for branching you need at least two subsequentSteps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not  know why this question got votes down. Anyway there is how I could solve the issue.

```
wizard.getProgressStep().mProperties.validated = false;
```

In the documention they didnt make mention of that property.